# jQuery Mobile: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery...' of undefined

Tags: jquery-mobile

I've got a jQuery Mobile project which is distributed in different files, e.g.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/methods.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!-- Termine Page -->
        <div data-role="page" id="firstPage">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
                <h1>Header 1</h1>
                ...
            </div><!-- /navbar -->

            <div data-role="content">
            ...
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>

secondPage.html

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="cordova-2.3.0.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" />

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/custom.css" />

        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/methods.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="pageTwo" class="ui-page">
            <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed" id="terminDetailSeiteHeader">
            <h1>Header 2</h1>
        </div>
        <div data-role="content">
                <div id="contentToFillWithDynamicListView"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Then, I got a script which should make a call to a php-Script and generate a listview:

```
function listViewCreation() {
    var url = 'http://www.myServer.com/myPhp.php?someParameters=1&callback=?';
        $.getJSON(url, function(data) {
            $('#contentToFillWithDynamicListView').empty();
            var collapsibleList = '<ul data-role="listview">';
            var myselfIsIncluded = 0;
            $.each(data, function(key, value) {
                collapsibleList += '<li>' + value['displayName'] + '</li>';
            });
            collapsibleList += '</ul>';

            $('#contentToFillWithDynamicListView').html(collapsibleList).trigger('create');
        });
    }
```

The .trigger('create') leads to the error... what am I missing?

**EDIT 1**

listViewCreation is called the following way:

```
$("#pageTwo").live("pageshow", function(e, data){
    listViewCreation();
});
```

**EDIT 2**
I'm fetching remote data from a different server, that seems to be the reason for the error; but I don't know how to solve it... I'm fetching data on both pages (1 and 2); for the first page it works, for the second it doesn't...

```
$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: In what file is the listViewCreation() method?

Comment: Your code seems to be ok as you can see here (slightly modified): http://jsfiddle.net/rhHUy/

Comment: What's the exact error (I mean after the "jQuery")?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'jQuery18304456543792039156' of undefined

Comment: I've tried the whole code. It works well so the problem is probably with your server data. Just to try, remove the phonegap library and instead of the data from the server, try some local data. If it works, you'll have some clue

Comment: please see my second edit; I'm fetching remote data, must have to do something with that...

Comment: Just a quick FYI, the .live() binding is removed in jquery 1.9 http://api.jquery.com/live/

Comment: @swalkner Just out of curiosity, did this problem suddenly begin occurring for you?  I've had some code that worked fine last week, but this week not so much.  Version control agrees with me.  I'm trying to figure out what all changed.  The answer from Gajotres is correct, but I need a way to refresh hundreds of elements and `pagecreate` seems to be the best way to do it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I can see you are using last stable version of jQuery mobile.

Your problem is

```
trigger('create');
```

it is not used for jQuery mobile listview restyling. You should use :

```
.listview('refresh');
```

instead. Don't trust official jQM documentation, **trigger('create')** should be deprecated. Every jQM widget has a function meant to refresh it, for example **button('refresh')**.

Also don't use **trigger('create')** when changing header, footer or content, it won't work, you can trigger pagecreate on the page:

```
trigger('pagecreate');
```

**EDIT :**

In case of:

> Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to
>   initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'

Call:

```
$('#listviewid').listview().listview('refresh');
```

First call will initialize it and second one will style it.

Find more about this topic in this **[ARTICLE](http://www.gajotres.net/jquery-mobile-and-how-to-enhance-the-markup-of-dynamically-added-content/)**.

Comment: am I getting it right? I've got to get the listview an id (<ul ... id="listviewid">), then $('#listviewid').listview('refresh'); - correct? because then I'm getting "Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on listview prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'refresh'"

Comment: Ok in that case you need to initialize it before, like this: $('#listviewid').listview().listview('refresh'); First listview() will initialize it and second one will style it.

Comment: unfortunately it doesn't work either; again the uncaught typeerror when doing the listview()... :(